# How can I return from the label to the loop? | TASM

Tags: assembly, tasm

I need the sum of numbers that are less than N, I created a loop and a condition. When the condition is met, we get into the label, however, it does not work to return from it. What should I do?

```
mov     [Sum],  0
        mov     cx,     [N]
        mov     ax,     1
        ForI:

                cmp ax, 10
                jl check
                ;add     [Sum],  ax
                inc     ax

        loop    ForI

        check:
            add [Sum], ax
```

Comment: Jump back again?

Comment: What does "it does not work to return from it" mean?

Comment: I need to go back into the loop to continue checking the following numbers

Comment: The loop stops after 1 element that matches the condition

Answer (score 3):

What I suggest is a simple pattern matching approach to translating control structures of structured statements.  What you're trying to accomplish is an if-statement nested within a loop, such as this:

```
ctr = N;
val = 0;
do {
   if ( val >= 10 )
       sum += val;
   val++;
} while ( --ctr >= 0 );
```

A do-while-loop has a structured statement pattern of the following:

```
do
    <loop-body>
while ( <condition> );
```

and the equivalent pattern in assembly language's if-goto-label style is:

```
Loop1:
    <loop-body>
    if ( <condition> ) goto Loop1;
```

An if-then structured statement has the following pattern:

```
if ( <condition> )
    <then-part>
```

The equivalent in assembly's if-goto-label style is:

```
    if ( <condition> is false ) goto EndIf1;
    <then-part>
EndIf1:
```

So, just put these two patterns together and your code will work the same as that C pseudo code.  These patterns keep the various parts of the structured statements in the same orientation, so if you put something in the wrong place it should be clear.

```
ctr = N;
val = 0;
do {
   if ( val >= 10 )               // <loop-body> starts here (inclusive)
       sum += val;                // <loop-body>
   val++;                         // <loop-body> ends here (inclusive)
} while ( --ctr >= 0 );
```

So, what you want the assembly code to look like is the do-while-loop pattern and then nested entirely within it as the loop-body is a compound statement (i.e. sequential statements) with one if- and one increment statement.  Translate the if-statement, nesting it in the same place as it appears in the loop-body of the do-while statement, and do the same with the `val++;` — locating it after the complete if-statement pattern and both together as the loop-body that is nested fully within the do-while loop as I've shown in C above.

---

There are other approaches that are easy for experienced assembly programmers (but error prone for beginners).  For example, you could fix the code in your post by adding some goto's (`jmp`) in the right places, but that won't necessarily teach you the concept of nested and sequential control structures using structured statements and how they related to the if-goto-label form.

The pattern match & translate approach will be less error prone the more code you have to translate, like doubly nested loops and such.